# How to get list of data within two date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, between

I would like to know what is the best way to get uniqueidentifier column within two date range my query as below

```
SELECT id, question, description
from Questions
where id between EffectiveFromDate and EffectiveToDate
```

Table structure of the question is:

```
[Id] Uniqueidentifier Code varchar(255) 
[Question] varchar(500) 
[EffectiveFromDate] datetime 
[EffectiveToDate] datetime 
[ModifiedDate] datetime
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: `uniqueidentifier column` means ?

Comment: Is id really a date column? (Very odd column name if that's the case...)

Comment: Id is uniqueidentifier column, I am trying to get list of questions which is valid between two dates. Table has EffectiveFromDate and EffectiveToDate columns

Comment: Give us some sample table data, expected result, and your current query!

Comment: What is the problem with current query? It seems perfectly valid to me. Though I normally prefer to use all keywords in upper case and instead of Questions I would have used [dbo].[Questions]

Comment: So you should have 4th column with date when question added.

Comment: when executing the query I will get following error "Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with datetime

Comment: <code>Id Uniqueidentifier
Code varchar(255)
Question varchar(500)
EffectiveFromDate datetime
EffectiveToDate datetime
ModifiedDate datetime</code>

Comment: @jks what is `EffectiveFrom`and `EffectiveTo` columns means? Are they used for self history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the table structure that you posted in your comment.

```
Id Uniqueidentifier Code varchar(255) 
Question varchar(500) 
EffectiveFromDate datetime 
EffectiveToDate datetime 
ModifiedDate datetime
```

If you want valid question between 2 dates:

```
Declare @DatetimeVar1 as Datetime = '2015-04-13 00:00:00'
Declare @DatetimeVar2 as Datetime = '2015-04-14 00:00:00'

Select * from Questions
where EffectiveFromDate between @DateTimeVar1 and @DateTimeVar2
or EffectiveToDate between @DateTimeVar1 and @DateTimeVar2
```

This checks that either the EffectiveFromDate or the EffectiveToDate is between the 2 dates you are querying for.

Answer (score 0):

As your question conveyed to me, try this and let me know if your requirement is different .

You need to pass a `DateTime` type column name to compare.

```
SELECT id, question, description FROM Questions
WHERE Id=YourID AND dateColumn between EffectiveFromDate and EffectiveToDate
```

Comment: Hi Varsha, Thank you very much for your suggestion. I don't have another date column to compare with, I will speak to our Architect team. Thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand **[BETWEEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx)**

> "Sql Between" Specifies a range to test.

Syntax:

```
select * from table_name
where
test_expression  BETWEEN begin_expression AND end_expression
```

> test_expression Is the expression to test for in the range defined by
>   begin_expressionand end_expression. test_expression must be the same
>   data type as both begin_expression and end_expression.
>
> begin_expression Is any valid expression. begin_expression must be the same data type
>   as both test_expression and end_expression.
>
> end_expression Is any valid expression. end_expression must be the
>   same data type as both test_expression and begin_expression.
>
> AND Acts
>   as a placeholder that indicates test_expression should be within the
>   range indicated by begin_expression and end_expression.

So,
for

```
SELECT id, question, description
from Questions
where id between EffectiveFromDate and EffectiveToDate
```

*id,EffectiveFromDate,EffectiveToDate must be the same data type*

and i think, it's not in .
hopefully you are trying to select all the `id` in a specific date.

so you need to try:

```
declare @startdate as date='01/02/2014'
declare @enddate as date='01/02/2015'

SELECT id, question, description
    from Questions
    where Cast(EffectiveFromDate as date) >=cast(@startdate as date)
and Cast(EffectiveToDate as date)<=cats(@enddate as date)
```